# How to configure Titan with embedded Cassandra?

Tags: configuration, cassandra, configuration-files, titan

I would like to set up a simple Titan instance with Cassandra in embedded mode for my application. There is no Rexster, Titan Server or clustering involved, I just want Titan locally inside my application. I've configured Titan itself according to the Titan documentation [here](http://s3.thinkaurelius.com/docs/titan/current/cassandra.html) and [here](http://s3.thinkaurelius.com/docs/titan/current/titan-config-ref.html#_storage_cassandra). This seems to work fine as Titan tries to fire up cassandra on startup.

The problem is that `cassandra.yaml` is referenced throughout the documentation, but I can't find an example of this file that works together with Titan. All I have found is the `cassandra.yaml` on [Titan GitHub](https://github.com/thinkaurelius/titan/blob/titan05/titan-cassandra/config/cassandra/cassandra.yaml), but it contains a lot of variable references (e.g. `${cassandra.token}`) and my cassandra instance apparently doesn't know how to deal with them.

Basically all I am looking for is a `cassandra.yaml` that works fine for a Cassandra instance embedded in Titan. Can anybody help me out?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you should start with the `cassandra.yaml` provided by cassandra itself:

https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/trunk/conf/cassandra.yaml

That would be free of any variables or other markup from Titan.

Comment: Yes, good idea. I tried to do that, unfortunately the Titan-embedded Cassandra rejected that file, stating that there were "unknown options" in it. After removing them, the glorious result was a `NullPointerException` somewhere deep inside Cassandra. My guess is that my version of Cassandra is different from the one for which this configuration file was designed. I actually solved it differently, see my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of back and forth (and lots of trial and error) I finally arrived at a working configuration. The way I did it was downloading the titan-cassandra 0.3.0 project from github and found a `cassandra.yaml` in it. I had to comment out a couple of parameters, as titan-cassandra 0.5.4 apparently does not accept them anymore.

It might not be perfect (if anybody has further suggestions, please tell me), but at least it works. Here it is, a `cassandra.yaml` compatible with titan-cassnadra 0.5.4. in embedded mode:

```
# Cassandra storage config YAML

# NOTE:
#   See http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/StorageConfiguration for
#   full explanations of configuration directives
# /NOTE

cluster_name: 'Test Cluster'

initial_token:

hinted_handoff_enabled: true
max_hint_window_in_ms: 10800000
hinted_handoff_throttle_in_kb: 1024
max_hints_delivery_threads: 2

authenticator: org.apache.cassandra.auth.AllowAllAuthenticator
authorizer: org.apache.cassandra.auth.AllowAllAuthorizer

partitioner: org.apache.cassandra.dht.RandomPartitioner

data_file_directories:
    - /tmp/cassandra/data

commitlog_directory: /tmp/cassandra/commitlog

disk_failure_policy: stop

key_cache_size_in_mb:
key_cache_save_period: 14400
# key_cache_keys_to_save: 100
row_cache_size_in_mb: 0
row_cache_save_period: 0
saved_caches_directory: /tmp/cassandra/saved_caches

commitlog_sync: periodic
commitlog_sync_period_in_ms: 10000
commitlog_segment_size_in_mb: 32

seed_provider:
    - class_name: org.apache.cassandra.locator.SimpleSeedProvider
      parameters:
          - seeds: "127.0.0.1"

concurrent_reads: 32
concurrent_writes: 32

memtable_flush_queue_size: 4

trickle_fsync: false
trickle_fsync_interval_in_kb: 10240


storage_port: 7000

ssl_storage_port: 7001

listen_address: localhost

start_native_transport: false
native_transport_port: 9042

start_rpc: true
rpc_address: localhost
rpc_port: 9160

rpc_keepalive: true

rpc_server_type: sync

thrift_framed_transport_size_in_mb: 15

thrift_max_message_length_in_mb: 16

incremental_backups: false

snapshot_before_compaction: false

auto_snapshot: true

column_index_size_in_kb: 64

in_memory_compaction_limit_in_mb: 64
multithreaded_compaction: false
compaction_throughput_mb_per_sec: 16
compaction_preheat_key_cache: true

read_request_timeout_in_ms: 10000
range_request_timeout_in_ms: 10000
write_request_timeout_in_ms: 10000
truncate_request_timeout_in_ms: 60000
request_timeout_in_ms: 10000

cross_node_timeout: false

endpoint_snitch: SimpleSnitch
dynamic_snitch_update_interval_in_ms: 100 
dynamic_snitch_reset_interval_in_ms: 600000
dynamic_snitch_badness_threshold: 0.1

request_scheduler: org.apache.cassandra.scheduler.NoScheduler

index_interval: 128

server_encryption_options:
    internode_encryption: none
    keystore: conf/.keystore
    keystore_password: cassandra
    truststore: conf/.truststore
    truststore_password: cassandra

client_encryption_options:
    enabled: false
    keystore: conf/.keystore
    keystore_password: cassandra

internode_compression: all
```

I had to remove a LOT of comments in this file due to character restrictions on StackOverflow answers. If you need information on any parameter, please download a cassandra distribution and look at the contained `cassandra.yaml` for details.